# Remix contract balance transfers Failing (Metamask / JS VM)

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer, solidity-0.6.x

There is an issue with my smart contract not transferring any funds to any other address on the connected ganache instance. Regardless if I choose "JavaScript VM" or connect to my Remix, the contract balance gets reduced to zero, but the transaction ends up failing and not actually
transferring any funds. Code:

```
pragma solidity > 0.6.0 < 0.7.0;

import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI_0.6.sol";

contract LoanContract is usingProvable {  
    address payable public ME = 0x6252039C9037A49a62f17edbdb26D9bDFffa9dF2;
    uint public balance;

     ...
     ...
     fallback() external payable {balance = address(this).balance;}
     function AddLender() payable public {
           balance = address(this).balance;
           num_lenders += 1;
     }
    function BPAYOUT() public {
     
        ME.transfer(address(this).balance);
        balance = address(this).balance;
        
        return;
    }
}
```

I have other unrelated functions and everything compiles. I have an Ethereum-bridge setup, Ganache running on 8545, and deposit functions so the contract definitely can receive / had funds on it. Deploys fine with metamask and JS VM, but only when I do the "BPAYOUT" function, I get an error that flashes way too quickly for me to see on Metamask, and Remix prints `false Transaction mined but execution failed`.
It also seems that the "to" txn output from Remix when I execute the function is different from the "ME" address I hardcoded in which seems strange. Please help me understand why the transfers don't go through! =)

Edit: I also get this gas-estimation error message from remix before the metamask errors out:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
[object Object] { "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode", "code": -32000, "data": { "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:89:13)\n at module.exports (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/gas/guestimation.js:142:32)", "name": "RuntimeError" } }

Comment: Does the contract deployed at `ME` have a payable fallback function?

Comment: @goodvibration I added in ```fallback() external payable {balance = address(this).balance;} ``` in there but am getting a pop-up error on Metamask which fails the transaction when I try to deposit. Is there something else I'm missing? I've tried adding in a receive() function as well which had the same issues =(

Comment: Yeah, you cannot spend more than 2300 gas in a fallback invoked from another contract (i.e., not from an off-chain transaction). Since `balance` is a storage variable, setting it to a non-zero value costs 5000 or 10000 if I remember correctly (depending on whether or not it was zero prior to that), which exceeds the stipend of 2300.

Comment: And I wrote the above under the assumption that you've added `fallback() external payable {balance = address(this).balance;}` in the contract deployed at the `ME` address.

Comment: @goodvibration thank you for the reply. If I'm deploying the contract from a different address other than ME, does that matter? B/c i'm just looking to disperse ether stored on the contract to that address when called by a non-"ME" address. Also, I'm not exactly sure what should go in the fallback() function.  I am also running into what looks like a ganache guestimation error (posted full error above). That likely has something to do with it, but appears even with an empty fallback.